# Retrieving tweets with only media_url

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I'm currently working on an app, and i only want to load tweets which contain a media_url. I have tried stopping it from loading the tweets into the tableView, however that lead to lots of blank tweets for obvious reasons.

Code i used for that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    id tweet = [self.timeline objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSString *example = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tweet valueForKeyPath:@"entities.media.media_url"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", example);

    if ([example isEqual: @"(null)"] ) {

    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"text"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"user.name"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

So now i'm looking for an alternative way which will successful only load tweets which have a media_url, and put them in the order that they come up. I'm using NSJSONSerialization to parse my data.

Code I used for that:

```
- (void)fetchData
{
    [_refreshHeaderView refreshLastUpdatedDate];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=199&include_entities=true"];
    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url 
                                                 parameters:nil 
                                              requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
    [request setAccount:self.account];    
    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
            NSError *jsonError = nil;
            id jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonError];
            if (jsonResult != nil) {
                self.timeline = jsonResult;
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                });                
            }
            else {
                NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Could not parse your timeline: %@", [jsonError localizedDescription]];
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                            message:message
                                           delegate:nil 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            }
        }
    }];
   [self performSelector:@selector(doneLoadingTableViewData) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];  
}
```

So I want to know is there anyway i can make the data that is added into timeline, only those of tweets which contain media_url, or is there a better way of doing this using a different method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try with something like this to check if the tweet contains or not a media url:

```
if([tweet valueForKey:@"entities.media.media_url"] == [NSNull null])
```